# Rich HTML editor in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tinymce, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm working on a WPF application where we need some rich HTML editing features. 
The application will typically generate some intitial HTML (tables and such) and present to the user, which in turn could edit before submitting the HTML back to the system. It would be really nice if the user could merge and delete cells in tables.

What I'm really looking for is a WYSIWYG editor, like [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) - only for WPF.

Up until now, I've experimented with converting HTML into a [Flow Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx), that the user can interact with in [Extended WPF Toolkit's RichTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox), by first [converting HTML to XAML](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e/sourcecode?fileId=21412&pathId=789957157).

I'm not very happy with the results, as the XAML code is unable to render the HTML correctly.

My feeling is that someone must have been struggeling with the same problems before me. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you've probably Googled this before coming here but anyway, tried this one? http://smithhtmleditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did some Googeling, but somehow I missed this. Looks like exactly what I need. I'd give you an "answer check" if this wasn't a comment.

Comment: I tried it out briefly but it seems to be doing a pretty good job based on what I saw and what people are saying in the discussion area. Just thought the chances that you had not tried that one already was pretty slim so that's why I added it as a comment instead of an answer :) Should I delete the comments and add an answer?

Comment: Yes, I believe that will be of most help for others...

Comment: Warning: Smith editor has a viral GPL license only!

Answer (score 6):

If you are not up to Rich Text Editor, rather pure HTML / XHTML editor then a recent release from SpiceLogic WPF HTML Editor Control could be the one that you may be interested in.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/WPF-HTML-Editor-Control-17

[image]

Yes, this editor control offers Table Manipulation from Context Menu, like Merge / Delete / Add Cells, Rows, Columns etc.

[image]

Comment: This looked promising to me. I looked into using Spice Logic's WPF HTML editor for my app, but sadly I learned it won't work for me and many other people because of limitations. The editor uses Win32 interop to render the browser instance. The downside to this is the editor's browser always overlays your WPF controls which is extremely noticeable when its embedded in a WPF scrollable area.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#notable-differences-in-output-behavior

Comment: Currently, the limitation you mentioned is actually a limitation of the Microsoft web browser control, not specifically the SpiceLogic WPF Editor Control's problem. The web browser control is hosted in a separate HWND that is always drawn on top of the WPF elements as stated in the documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952(v=vs.110).aspx. You may face such an issue in some limited scenario and there are workarounds for those scenarios. SpiceLogic is working on releasing a new version using WebView2 which is Chromium-based, and then this problem should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this project](http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor) (now replicated [here](https://github.com/AfterbuyAxel/WPF-RichText-Editor)). It is a wpf rich editor with HTML capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 

This approach is similar to the one I described in the question, converting HTML to XAML and presenting it in WPF. 

It still doesn't solve my problem with HTML-tables that need to be edited in an WYSIWYG manner.

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 3):

The Telerik wpf rich edit control imports and exports to HTML format making it a way to edit html without relying on a web browser control.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idea and provide source code .Please check the project [C# WPF WYSIWYG HTML Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/870549/Csharp-WPF-WYSIWYG-HTML-Editor)

Answer (score 0):

Try [WPF RichText Editor](https://github.com/ngaillet/WPF-RichText-Editor) Control (also available on NuGet).